# Instagram Subscription API get response hub.challenge

Tags: node.js, instagram-api

I'm reading the Instagram API docs https://www.instagram.com/developer/subscriptions/

And I understand the necessary steps

but on this line

```
In order to verify the subscription, your server must 
respond to the GET request with the hub.challenge parameter only:
```

After Instagram sends a POST request to my callback, when they state "server must respond to GET request" does that mean when they call my GET callback, I instantly send a post request within the GET callback. Inside this post request I send the hub.challenge to " https://api.instagram.com/v1/subscriptions/"

so something like

```
getInstagramSubscription(req,res){
     //Grab hub.challenge and send post request to https://api.instagram.com/v1/subscriptions/

},
```

I tried using [instagram-node-lib](https://github.com/mckelvey/instagram-node-lib)

```
 getInstagramSubscription(req,res){

     var handshake =  Instagram.subscriptions.handshake(req, res);

},
```

but once I deploy on heroku with this curl request

```
 curl -F 'client_id=client_id' \
 -F 'client_secret=secret' \
 -F 'object=username' \
 -F 'aspect=media' \
 -F 'verify_token=myVerifyToken' \
 -F 'callback_url=callback_url/subscriptions' \
 https://api.instagram.com/v1/subscriptions/
```

I'm still getting a Challenge verification failed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, so apparently you just respond with with the hub.challenge like so

```
    getInstagramSubscription(req,res){
     console.log(req.query)
     //Just send back the hub.challenge 
     return res.send(req.query['hub.challenge']);
}
```

I also had a couple errors with correct callback url